# recover file destroyed by old .swp file

Tags: crash-recovery

I saved and closed a file I was editing.  When I opened it again a minute later, vim gave the warning that appears when a .swp file is present.  I selected the recover option, but the "recovered" file did not have any of my recent work.  Then I checked the dates.  Somehow, the .swp file was last changed two months ago.  Two questions:
How could a .swp file suddenly appear from so long ago?  I have been regularly editing that file ever since, and this is the first time that has appeared.
More importantly, is there any way I can recover the version that existed a few minutes ago?

Comment: For future reference to people browsing this question: [Here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320150/176250)'s the accepted answer.

Comment: Please add your link to an answer so this can be marked completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: search partition for fragments of the file using `strings`, then pass the returned offset to `dd` as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320150/176250